# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `python3`to create a text game.

My code:

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1,99)
guess = 0
tries = 0
print (" AHOY! I'm the Dead Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries.")
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input ("What's yer guess?")
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, landlubber!")

    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    print ("Avast! Ye got it ! Found my secret, ye did!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")
    print ("The secret number was "), secret
```

After run, I get

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

when I type 40

I don't know why it appeared like this.

Comment: try if int(guess) < secret:

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x' `input()` function return `int` by default. In order to get an object of type `int`, you need to explicitly type-cast it:

```
guess = int(input ("What's yer guess?"))
```

Currently `guess` is string variable and `secret` is int so you can not use operator '<' with string and int.

**Updated code:**

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1,99)
guess = 0
tries = 0
print (" AHOY! I'm the Dead Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries.")
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input ("What's yer guess?"))
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, landlubber!")

    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    print ("Avast! Ye got it ! Found my secret, ye did!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")
    print ("The secret number was "), secret
```

Comment: how can I change this code correctly

Comment: @AnsonNM Updated answer with code.